# Rails Initializer Halting

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just about to publish a Rails project on GitHub that requires a user renaming and configuring a few YML files or setting environmental variables. The application has a few custom initializers and I'm wondering what the best way to enforce the presence of the above is? Currently I'm using the following snippet in one of my initializers:

```
# config/initializers/omniauth.rb

config = YAML::load(File.read("#{Rails.root}/config/omniauh.yml"))[Rails.env] rescue {}
config['twitter' ] ||= {}
config['facebook'] ||= {}

twitter_key     = config['twitter' ]['key']     || ENV['OMNIAUTH_TWITTER_KEY'    ]
twitter_secret  = config['twitter' ]['secret']  || ENV['OMNIAUTH_TWITTER_SECRET' ]
facebook_key    = config['facebook']['key']     || ENV['OMNIAUTH_FACEBOOK_KEY'   ]
facebook_secret = config['facebook']['secret']  || ENV['OMNIAUTH_FACEBOOK_SECRET']

[twitter_key, twitter_secret, facebook_key, facebook_secret].each do |parameter|
  throw "Rename and configure 'omniauth.yml.sample'." if parameter.nil? or parameter.empty?
end

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :twitter , twitter_key , twitter_secret
  provider :facebook, facebook_key, facebook_secret
end
```

Is it standard practice to `throw` from initializers or does Rails support a better way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fine. But you may also want to add a call to `Rails.logger.fatal`.

Comment: `Rails.logger.fatal` doesn't seem to do anything in the initializer. Do I need to configure anything special to use that?

Comment: Not sure. Does it log anything into the `log/#{env}.log` file?

Comment: I just realized it is writing to the logs, but not halting the start of the server (or printing to the output when running `rails s`).

Answer (score 1):

That seems perfectly acceptable to me, and is how I'd go about it (except I'd use `raise` instead of `throw` ;P)